# Android ViewPager fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I would like to ask if someone now's, is it possible to force `ViewPager` to instantiate one item at a time, not two as it does on default? Because I have one `ViewPager` with three fragments and one of them contains `EditText` which must force soft keyboard to show. The problem is that `ViewPager` instantiate two fragments at a time an when I come from third fragment to second, first is ceated and it forces soft keyboard to show on fragment with no `EditText`... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't force the `ViewPager` not to create at least one offscreen fragment. That's simply necessary for the animation to work.

As a workaround, you might check if the fragment is currently displayed and depending on that show the keyboard. You can check this by overriding `setMenuVisibility`

```
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
    if (visible) {
        // show keyboard
    }
}
```

Comment: There is [setUserVisibleHint()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean))